# Pointer to Vector of pointers

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, memory-leaks

I am in the process of changing some code that someone else has written. In one part of the code they have used a pointer to a vector of pointers.

```
            class2 *pointofclass2 = new class2();

        class1 * pointofclass1 = new class1(.....)

        pointofclass2->push_back(pointofclass1);
```

Then later the code

```
    delete pointofclass2;
```

Now I think this is causing a memory leak. I have never come across this before so not sure if this is the cause or not? Any help would be greatly appreciated. If so what is the correct way of freeing the memory?

Comment: So does `class2` inherit from `vector`? You should definitely delete `pointofclass2` in the way you do, but are you wondering if `pointofclass1` is still residing somewhere in memory? It should be cleaned up in `class2`'s destructor.  How do you know you are leaking memory? Valgrind?

Comment: A) I have a memory leak. e.g. when I run the program it continues to use up more and more memory (and it shouldn't) B) I get possibly lost from Valgrind which shows the line with class1 * pointofclass1 =  new class1 (....).

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting pointofclass2 but are probably not deleting the vector that holds pointers of class1 in the destructor of class1. Where is the object created in new class1(...) getting deleted? This is C++, there is no automatic garbage collection.

Now if class2 is a vector you don't really *need* to create a pointer to it since vectors will allocate memory on the heap anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Unless elements added via `push_back()` are destroyed in `class2`'s dtor, this is a leak.